# Should loops with logic and html output go in the model or the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, loops

I'm new to OOP and MVC and currently building a website using CodeIgniter.

There seems to be a lot of contrasting information about whether loops should be in the view or the model.

On the one hand I'm trying to keep all my html markup inside the views, but on the other hand I want to keep my messy PHP logic outside of the view. Plus I also need to format the data inside my loops using functions located in my model.

What's the best way to go about organising this?

Here is a simplified version of my current implementation:

**View**

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $albumTracklistHtml ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**Controller**

```
$data = [
    '$albumTracklistHtml' => $this->MyModel->getAlbumTracklistHtml()
];

$this->load->view('myPage', $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function getAlbumTracklistHtml()
{
    //$this->tracklisting returned from db call in other function
    foreach($this->tracklisting as $song) {
        $mp3 = $this->convertToAmazonUrl($song['mp3']);
        $art = $this->formatArtUrl($song['art']);
        $name = $this->formatTrackName($song['name']);
        $class = 'mp3';
        $btn ='';
        if(substr($name, 0, 1) == '*') {
            $class = 'load mp3';
            $btn = '<span class="playBtn"></span>';
        }
        <li class="'.$class.'" '.$mp3.'>'.$btn.$name.'</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd move it into the view. Models shouldn't contain html markup

Comment: There's markup in your model, which is definitely wrong. Get the model to return an array (or an array of arrays, or an array of classes, whichever is a better fit) and then do that rendering in the view.

Comment: Thanks guys. But what should I do about calling model functions inside my view?  e.g. convertToAmazonUrl()

Comment: You don't. You would process the URL in the model, or use a helper to do the conversion. `MyClass::convertToAmazonUrl($url) // returns $amazonURL`. You (should) never call model functions from a view.

Comment: `convertToAmazonUrl` sounds like it is logic, rather than presentation. Thus, I'd leave it where it is. Don't be afraid to do some processing in the model to prepare the output of a method to match the name of the method, and then loop again in the view to do plain rendering.

Comment: Well ... since you are using CodeIgniter, it has nothing to do with MVC or OOP.

Comment: @tereško - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean what I wrote: CodeIgniter does not implement MVC design pattern and it does not apply any of the OO practices and principles.

Comment: CodeIgniter does implement MVC pattern - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html - and is OO as uses classes and objects!

Comment: @Disco - don't let people put you off using CI. My understanding from reading a variety of thoughts on it here is that the design patterns it uses are non-optimal, even though it is miles better than not having a framework at all. Framework recommendations are probably o/t here, but Symfony2 and Laravel, I believe, are thought to engineer things a lot better (via dependency injection). Short story: carry on as you are, but always have one eye open for how you can improve things `:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very generally speaking, and keep in mind that this isn't a hard and fast rule and if you ask ten different people you'll get ten slightly different answers, but the job of the model view and controller are essentially:

1. The model provides a way for the controller & view to access data from another source (a database, for instance). It's basically an abstraction on whatever your data is stored in.
2. The views simply display data they are given.
3. Controllers connect the model's data with the view, so it can display the data.

I would argue that the example code you've posted is just fine, and fits these definitions. Your model retrieves the data (or processes it), the controller hands the resulting data to the view, and the view simply displays it.

However, I also think it's fine (and *generally I prefer this*) for the model to simply return a list of items, and then for the view to loop through them and display each one. Of course, the view "shouldn't" be doing a lot of processing, but outputting HTML for each item seems like exactly what it should be doing. The reason I prefer this is purely for separating concerns - your models should be fairly HTML-agnostic. As in, if you ever wrote a non-web-based application to interact with the same data, **it could use the same models**. Because of this, I would put any HTML-rendering code in my views. Even though it requires some looping logic.

At the end of the day, though, I don't think it matters *that* much in your case. If you strongly prefer putting the loop in the model, go with that. The **most important thing** is just to develop your own conventions, and then **stick to them**.

Comment: Thanks CmdrMoozy. This was very helpful. I now loop over and process the data in the model and then return a new array to the view which then renders to html. Looks so much neater now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do the view:

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($album->getTracks() as $track): ?>
            <li
                class="<?php echo $track->isPlayable() ? 'load mp3' : '' ?>"
            >
                <span class="playBtn">
                    <?php echo $track->getName() ?>
                </span>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

This assumes that you've passed a variable called `$album`, and that a method offered therein returns an array of type `Track`.

You can return arrays if you like as well, however I prefer objects as you can convert complex conditions to simple, meaningful names. Thus, rather than your '*' test, the programmer calls `$track->isPlayable()`, which makes much more sense, and doesn't need commenting in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it depends on what the loop is doing. One can have view specific loops. You can loop through html tags that display elements dynamically and that should go in the view.

```
for($controller_sent_array as $element) 
{
    echo "<h4>$element</h4>";
}
```

However things like looping through file input should go in the controller/model side. I make a point of being vague here because the choice of what should be in models verses controllers depends on framework optimizations. However what is important is that the model and controller are not sending html to be rendered. Rather, they should process data either from a database or user input or network connection, and package that data for the view to figure out. To this end you also need loops.

```
// This is not a safe way to do this in real life...
for($_POST as $post_input)
{
    $this->your_database_library->save_input($post_input);
}
```

Consider your framework selection with respect to what loops are processing what where, but loops should be used when needed in the model, view, or controller.